# Parsing match operator and refactoring switch cases

Tags: .net, design-patterns, refactoring, switch-statement, strategy-pattern

I need a function that will take operands/operators as parameters and provide the evaluation result.
The problem that I am facing is how to elegantly parse an operator.

Sample code is as below

```
internal static bool Evaluator(double operand1, double operand2, string operation)
{
    bool evaluation = false;
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "<":
            evaluation = operand1 < operand2;
            break;

        case ">":
            evaluation = operand1 > operand2;
            break;

        case "<=":
            evaluation = operand1 <= operand2;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return evaluation;
}
```

I can put operators in enum (or extendable enum) and use strategy pattern to remove the switch case.
The issue remains, I cannot parse operators. 
example

```
     op1="<";
     var operation = Operation.Parse(op1);
     var result = operand1 <--  operation should come here --> operand2.
```

Please suggest how to refactor above code (Evaluator function) elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch statement is the simplest implementation of a chain of responsibility pattern, the purpose of which is to route your problem to the correct handler.  The classic GoF implementation is the Linked List.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) has a good article, as does [NetObjectives](http://www.netobjectivestest.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=TheChainOfResponsibilityPattern).

Another good implementation for you problem is the Registry implementation.  This works here because the rule is always the same -- match a given key to an operation.  Fill in this abstraction, backing it with a dictionary.  Pre-load the dictionary with the operations you know about.

```
public abstract class OperationRegistry
{
   public abstract void RegisterOperation(string symbol, Func<double, double, bool> operation);
   public abstract Func<double, double, bool> GetOperation(string symbol);
}
```

FWIW, I'd prefer to see a new class instead of Func, but perhaps that is just me.

Comment: dictinary implementation seems clean to me. regarding Func, you are right, a new Class is better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
public static Func<double, double, bool> ParseOperation(string operation)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "<":
            return (x, y) => x < y;

        case ">":
            return (x, y) => x > y;

        case "<=":
            return (x, y) => x <= y;

        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var op = ParseOperation("<");
Console.WriteLine(op(1, 2)); // true
```

Comment: very close, and neat. I am looking something similar, but i also want to remove switch-case to add few more operators later.